Why does Ash Wednesday not appear in the list of holy days of obligation?
I was surprised to learn that Ash Wednesday is not one of the Catholic Holy Days of Obligation (see this list) although it is listed here as "important liturgical observances".
I thought Catholics are obliged to go to Mass on Ash Wednesday, or do they just need to fast (according to precept #4 because precept #1 says to "... attend Mass and holy days of obligation ...")?
Why not make Ash Wednesday into a "holy day of obligation"?  Wouldn't that day be at least as important (spiritually) as the 3 (out of 6 non-Sunday days) dedicated to Mary?
(I'm also surprised that Good Friday is not in the list either, but I don't want to clutter this question).

Good Friday is not a holy day of obligation (i.e. a day one is obliged to attend Mass) for the simple reason that Mass is not celebrated on Good Friday.
